# Get value from c10::Dict<c10::IValue, c10::IValue> in Pytorch C++

Tags: c++, pytorch, torch, libtorch, torchscript

I'm using a TorchScript Model on Pytorch C++ Frontend.

The model in Python returns an `output` dict as  `Dict[str, List[torch.Tensor]]`.

When I use it in C++, it returns a `c10::Dict<c10::IValue, c10::IValue>`. What is the equivalent of this Python code:

```py
value_a = output['key_a']
value_b = output['key_b']
```

in C++ to get value from `c10::Dict`?

I have tried this but it does not work.

```cpp
torch::IValue key_a("key_a");
torch::IValue key_b("key_b");
c10::IValue value_a = output[key_a];
c10::IValue value_b = output[key_b];
std::cout << value_a << std::endl;
std::cout << value_b << std::endl;
```

And error:

```
error: type 'c10::Dict<c10::IValue, c10::IValue>' does not provide a subscript operator
```

Comment: What is the C++ type of C10:Dict?

Comment: @Surt. I'm not sure. C10:Dict is from libtorch. You can read more about it here: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/structc10_1_1_i_value.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find header file of `c10:Dict` [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/core/Dict.h). What you want is `at` method ([defined here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/core/Dict.h#L317)), so:

```
auto value_a = output.at(key_a);
```

Should do the trick.

Also you don't have to create `torch::IValue key_ay("key_a")` explicitly, this should be sufficient:

```
auto value_a = output.at("key_a");
```